# Inserir abstract e keywords em duas línguas no mesmo texto em latex (artigo)

Tags: latex

Olá,

estou escrevendo um artigo em inglês seguindo o template do jornal em latex.

Nesse template, o comando abstract (\abstract{}) vem seguido do keywords (\keywords{}) e logo após vem \maketitle. Porém, preciso escrever em seguida do abstract e keywords uma versao deles em outra língua, diferente do inglês.

Já procurei em vários sites uma solucao que funcione pro meu caso, porém nao encontrei ainda nada. Se coloco o \maketitle logo após o título e autores, o abstract e keywords nao aparecem no texto. Se tento algo como \begin{otherlanguage}{ngerman} or \selectlanguage{ngerman}, também nao funciona.

Fico feliz com qualquer sugestao ou ideia para me ajudar.

Obrigada,
Maira